# How to forward data from one component and post to another component Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, formkit

Im very new to Vue.js, Formkit and am a bit lost in how to proceed.
I have one component which creates a uniqueID(unique enough for us) when mounted.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <span>
        <p class="solid" :for="id"> ID: {{ id }}</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </template>
<script>

export default {
  name: "unique-id",
  data() {
    return {
       id: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
 this.id = 
   (Date.now().toString(32) +
      Math.random().toString(16)).replace(/\./g, '')
  }
}
</script>
```

I then need to submit that id and a couple of other bits of data to another component.

```
<script>
import uniqueID from "./id.vue";

</script>
 export default { 
        name: "BasicItem-page",
              data ()
         {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
          return {
             data:{  }
           }            
        },
    components:
              {
              uniqueID,
              }
}
  </script>
<template>
    <html lang="en">
 
    <FormKit
    type="form"
    id="BasicItem"
    v-model="data"
    @submit="submit"
    >
    <h3>Add Item</h3>
    <span>
    <uniqueID/>
    </span>
    <FormKit
        type="floatingLabelTextInput"
        name="title"
        label="Title"
        validation="required|text"
      />
      <FormKit
        type="floatingLabelTextInput"
        name="location"
        label="Location"
        validation="required|text"
      />
   
<uniqueID/>
      <FormKit
        type="floatingLabelTextInput"
        name="item_title"
        label="Item Title"
        validation="required|text"
      />
      <FormKit
        type="floatingLabelTextInput"
        name="item_location"
        label="Item Location"
        validation="required|text"
      />
 
   </template>
```

I'm using the 'id' component at other places within the above form which also complicates matters
How do I get the ID?

I cant seem to be able to get the ID.  Ive tried to create a composable which didnt give any errors but no data.

```
import { ref } from 'vue' 

export function NewuniqueID() {
   const id  = (Date.now().toString(32) +
      Math.random().toString(16)).replace(/\./g, '')
  return { id }
}
```

Comment: For pass data from parent to child component, you can use props method. Read more about [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html)

Comment: What's the point of that id component? Is the template really that simple? A reasonable decision is to decouple id generation from the presentation. " Ive tried to create a composable" - how did you use it?

Comment: @anilkumar  When I try to add it using prop in child  prop:[ id ], and add The new ID is : {{ id}} in parent I get nothing.

Comment: @EstusFlask  The point of the id component is to create a unique ID for the item thats to be added, The user needs to see this.  Its also used at other points in the app to create IDs  for other items which are child elements of the item created above.  The composable is created,  import {NewuniqueID} from "../composables/uniqueid";

 export default { 
  setup(){
    const {newid} = NewuniqueID()
    return {newid }
  }, 

The new ID is : {{ newid}}  nothing is displayed

Comment: It could be "stupid" representation comp, or just be a simple layout because all it does is `<p>`. You return `{ id }` but expect `newid`. Different key